# Add lines between each cell in a Bivariate seaborn histplot blocks

Tags: seaborn

I've been trying to add lines between each cell in a `sns.histplot` with two variables same than a `sns.heatmap` but I've failed every single time.

I've tried with `linewidths` argument since it is the way for doing that with a heatmap

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.histplot(penguins, x="bill_depth_mm", y="body_mass_g", linewidths=1)
```

but nothing changes. I know I could aggregate the data first and then use a heatmap but I feel so dumb that I can do it in a single way. I'm using seaborn 0.11.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By default, the edges of each cell get the same color as the cell. Setting an explicit `edgecolor` will make the borders visible.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC! I had no idea and it was so simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.histplot(
    penguins, x="bill_depth_mm", y="body_mass_g", linewidths=1,
    edgecolor="w"  # <-- Here's what you're missing
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It was so simple and I literally tried to do some tricky thing reading the source code haha